# s3fs disable cache

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3fs, disable-caching

I have problem with viewing video from my bucket on S3.
I'm using EC2 instance. Bucket mounted as folder via s3fs. When i try to load a big file i have a pause before starting download. In this pause, i see that file download (cache) to EC2. When it was cached, file start to download in browser.
I try to configure s3fs and disable cache, but option -o use_cache="" doesn't work. I try to use s3fslite, but it is also cache files before sending it to user.

How to disable caching? Maybe there is some faster solution, that can help me to use s3 bucket like folder on EC2?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to download the files, either serve them directly from s3, or use cloudfront.

If you are trying to control access to the file. Use signed URLs which will give them user a certain amount of time to access the file before the link expires.

Comment: In case we use directly link to s3, will be H.264 streaming module work with this link? I'm using this module to seek on video file via flash app. And link looks like http://server.com/videofile.mp4?start=20 (it means that video start from 20 second)....

Comment: Im not sure if s3 supports that, but you can configure Cloudfront to be a streaming distribution. More info on [aws cloudfront docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingStreamingDistributions.html).